# UrlFetchApp timeout

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to download some reports using Google Sheets.

So basically I'm using `UrlFetchApp`to do the job and it does when the response is received within 1 minute. If the response is taking more than a minute then the request times out and the reports are not downloaded.

This is the options that I'm sending with `UrlFetchApp`:

```
var options = {
  "method" : "post",
  "header" : "someHeaders",
  "muteHttpExceptions" : true,
  "followRedirects" : false,
  "Content-Encoding" : "gzip",
  "payload" : "somePayload"
}
```

and then a simple call of `.fetch()`.

Is there a way to increase the timeout or any workaround for it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although it's not publicly documented, I realized by testing that fetch functions for `UrlFetchApp` [1] have a 1 minute timeout. There's a Feature Request open to extend or allow to configure the `UrlFetchApp` timeout [2].

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app

[2] https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36761852