# How many seconds are the URLFetchApp.fetch PDF limit?

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets, urlfetch

```js
const A = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportUrl + ss.getSheetByName("A").getSheetId(), params).getBlob().setName('A.pdf')
```

In Google Apps Script, Google Sheets

There is the time limit for fetching PDF blob from URL. How many seconds are they?

Comment: In the current stage, I think that when UrlFetchApp is run, the error by the timeout occurs after 60 seconds. But this is from my experience. I cannot find about this at the official document. I apologize for this.

Comment: Thank you very much. So if I want to fetch several times in a row, I need to sleep more than one minute? 
 Utilities.sleep(60000); ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is an undocumented timeout for UrlFetchApp (the timeout will be the same regardless of requested resource type). See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59303291) to this question (quoted below):

> Although it's not publicly documented, I realized by testing that
> fetch functions for UrlFetchApp [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59303291) have a 1 minute timeout. There's a
> Feature Request open to extend or allow to configure the UrlFetchApp
> timeout [2](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).
>
> [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59303291)
> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app
>
> [2](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36761852

Looks like that feature request is still open several years later.

Also worth mentioning that a script has a 6 minute execution time, so if you exceed that, your script will also timeout. [You can see more quotas / limits here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).